# ObjectDisposedException while Showing a Form

Tags: c#, winforms, objectdisposedexception

I keep getting an ObjectDisposedExpection when I need to get a Form to show.
Do you guys maybe know how to do this? In the foreach by NotitiesForm.Show() I get the error ObjectDisposedExpection. I am programming in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 C#.

```
RichTextBox NotitiesTB = new RichTextBox();
private Form NotitiesForm;

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="label"></param>
/// 
public void NotitiesLatenZien()
{
    if (filename != null)
    {                
        BRTSignal signal = new BRTSignal(filename);
        BRTEventRepository Notities = new BRTEventRepository(signal);

        List<IBRTNote> note = Notities.ReadNotes();

        BRTEventService TijdNotities = new BRTEventService(signal);
        TijdNotities.MakeNoteTimesRelativeToTrack(note, 1);

        //TextBox NotitiesTB = new TextBox();
        //NotitiesTB.Name = "Notities";

        if (NotitiesForm == null)
        {
            NotitiesForm = new Form();
        }              

        NotitiesForm.Height = 600;
        NotitiesForm.Width = 1000;
        NotitiesForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        NotitiesForm.MaximizeBox = false;
        NotitiesForm.Disposed +=NotitiesForm_Disposed;

        NotitiesForm.Text = "Notities";

        NotitiesTB.Multiline = true;
        NotitiesTB.Height = 600;
        NotitiesTB.Width = 980;
        NotitiesTB.ReadOnly = true;

        NotitiesTB.Clear();

        //NotitiesTB.Click += NotitiesTB_Click;

        //NotitiesTB.SelectionStart = Convert.ToInt32(referenceLineSelectedPage);

        NotitiesTB.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;

        NotitiesTB.Name = "Notities";

        NotitiesForm.Controls.Add(NotitiesTB);

        foreach (IBRTNote notes in Notities.ReadNotes())
        {
            //string test = Convert.ToString((notes.Time));
            //textBox1.Text = String.Concat(textBox1.Text, string.Concat(Environment.NewLine, notes.Text));
            if (NotitiesTB.Text == "")
            {
                NotitiesTB.Text += new BRTToDotNET.RTDateTime((long)notes.Time).ToDotNet().ToString() + "     " + notes.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                NotitiesTB.Text += "\r\n" + new BRTToDotNET.RTDateTime((long)notes.Time).ToDotNet().ToString() + "     " + notes.Text;
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("\r\n" + notes.Text);
            NotitiesForm.Show();
            NotitiesForm.BringToFront();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Er blijkt een .sig file te missen. Controleer of u een .sig file heeft ingeladen.");
    }
}

private void NotitiesForm_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NotitiesForm = null;
}
```

Comment: What line throws this exception?

Comment: A Form object is a one-time-use object.  After it is closed, it is not usable anymore and you have to create a new one.  The `NotitiesForm` variable is getting you in trouble.  At a minimum, you need to subscribe the FormClosed event so you can set that variable back to `null`.  With high odds that the entire variable is just not useful since you never actually re-use the form object.  Just delete it.

Comment: Where do you `new` the `NotitiesTB`? Do you ever dispose it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted seem "good enough". That is, you set the `NotitiesForm` variable when the object is disposed, and you create a new one if it's null. As long as all this code executes in the main UI thread, that part is fine.

But note that all controls in a `Form` are disposed of when the `Form` is disposed. So your `NotitiesTB` control will be disposed of the first time your `NotitiesForm` is closed. You then add that control to the next `Form` instance you create, and when it's shown, you get the exception because you're trying to show a `Form` containing a control that has already been disposed.

The right way to do this would be to design an actual `Form` subclass *that already contains the* `RichTextBox` *instance you want*. Then you don't have to keep adding a new instance to each new instance of the `Form` you create.

Barring that, then you need to create a new `RichTextBox` instance to go with each new `Form` instance you create, e.g. in the same place where you have the `NotitiesForm = new Form();` statement.